# I want to get a previous year and month as id from my data but the result is not not correct

Tags: ssms

```
select 
 (year(dt)*100)+month(dt) as month_id,
 (year(dt)*100)+month(dt)-1 as month_id_LM,
  Level_6 as Model_Name,
 max(Unit_PriceOTR) as OTR_Highest,
 min(Unit_PriceOTR) as OTR_Lowest

from
   edw.[eview].[TB_R_CARPRICEOTR_APM]
where Level_6 = 'TOYOTA YARIS'
group by
(year(dt)*100)+month(dt),
Level_6
order by month_id
```

--month_id_LM shows month 0 which does not make sense.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `DATEFROMPARTS` which will give you the first day in that month. Then you can just subtract a month:

```sql
select 
 v.month_id,
 dateadd(month, -1, v.month_id) as month_id_LM,
 Level_6 as Model_Name,
 max(Unit_PriceOTR) as OTR_Highest,
 min(Unit_PriceOTR) as OTR_Lowest
from
   edw.[eview].[TB_R_CARPRICEOTR_APM]
cross apply (values
   (datefromparts(year(dt), month(dt), 1))
) v(month_id)
where Level_6 = 'TOYOTA YARIS'
group by
  v.month_id,
  Level_6
Level_6
order by
  month_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure there are functions to help you. On a quick search, I could find the `DATEADD` function.

You can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

One of the examples is this one:

> Subtract two months from a date, then return the date:
>
> `SELECT DATEADD(month, -2, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;`

Comment: Column 'edw.eview.TB_R_CARPRICEOTR_APM.DT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Suitable for a comment, but not comprehensive enough for an answer.